# NPM FontAwesome install --dev

Tags: npm, installation, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to install fontawesome 5 pro with NPM and Webpack. Something i can't get my head around is the command:

```
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Why using --save-dev, because what i understand is that -dev will install the package under devDependencies what only will work in dev modes. What if we switch it to prod mode, could we still use fontawesome?

Could somebody explain why most use the - dev?

Answer (score 0):

-dev means development purpose

e.g. `npm install should --save-dev`

You will use this option when you want to **download a package for developers** , such as grunt, gulp, then use this option. Thus, when you are distributing your code to production, these dependencies will not be available.

As an example, let say, you want to use grunt as your task runner. This package is required for development purpose. Thus, you should use *–save-dev* here.

`npm install grunt --save-dev`